# How to get specific output for a certain run time of a for loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to design a program that outputs the modulus of each fibonacci number given a certain number of terms to run. I also want this program to output when the number is even, divisible by 5, is a zero, or all three. so essentially it needs a specific output for every third, fifth and fifteenth time the loop is run hence why I tried using a bunch of if statements. If you could please guide me in the right direction or tell me what kind of code/format to use i think i'll be able to figure out. Thanks.

```
 sample output: for a 17 term input
    1: 1
    2: 1
    3: 2 - even
    4: 3
    5: 5 - divisible by 5
    6: 8 - even
    7: 3
    8: 1
    9: 4 - even
    10: 5 - divisible by 5
    11: 9
    12: 4 - even
    13: 3
    14: 7
    15: 0 - even -divisible by 5 - ends in zero
    16: 7
    17: 7


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

  int terms, n, next1, next2, first = 0, second = 1;




  cout << "Welcome to the Fibonacci sequence checker!" << endl;
  cout << "How many terms do you want to check?" << endl;
  cin >> terms;


  for ( int n = 1; n < terms; n++)
      {
    if (n <= 1)
      next2 = n;

    else
      {
        next1 = first + second;
        next2 = (first + second) % 10;
        first = second;
        second = next1;
      }

    if(next2 == 2 || next2 == 4 || next2 == 6 || next2 == 8)
      {
      cout << next2 << " - even";
      }
    if(next2 == 5)
      {
        cout << next2 << " - divisible by 5";
          }
    if(next2 == 0)
      {
      cout << " - even - divisible by 5 - ends in a zero";
      }


      }


  return 0;
}
```

sample output:
    1: 1
    2: 1
    3: 2 - even
    4: 3
    5: 5 - divisible by 5
    6: 8 - even
    7: 3
    8: 1
    9: 4 - even
    10: 5 - divisible by 5
    11: 9
    12: 4 - even
    13: 3
    14: 7
    15: 0 - even -divisible by 5 - ends in zero
    16: 7
    17: 7

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to check if the number is even just check the modulus by 2, no need to check if the last digit is 2 or 4 or 6 or 8. I would substitute all your checks with `next1%2==0`, `next1%5==0` and `next1%10==0`, also you need to change every `cout<<next2` to `cout<<next1` because `next2` is modulus of 10 of `next1`. Also as a good practice I suggest you to read Straustrup C++ book to get the basics of C++.

Comment: I made a revision to the description and added a sample output.